# Wrong shape of the inserted face the insert in circle

Tags: faces, geometry

When I insert in this circle I get not matching shape of the face. That is wrong with it? The circle inside should be matching the external circle. Extrusion was done with I (insert) function. The initial circle had one N-gon and 32 vertices. [image]

Comment: Please expand the question, it looks fine to me.

Comment: Circle inside should be matching external circle next to it. Because of some unknown reason, it is oval.

Comment: Still please expand the question with your process on how you extrude and insert the face.

Comment: With I (insert) function

Comment: Have you applied rotation and scale to the object before inseting?

Comment: No. Is that an issue?

Answer (score 1):

Try to go to object mode and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>  and select *To All Transforms* and now try to insert face.